# Why does SQL/PHP outputs double the information?

Tags: php, mysqli, foreach, while-loop

Database (named `countries`):

```
ID         NAME              ISO         TAG
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1          Netherlands       NL          Dutch
2          Germany           DE          Deutsch
3          Poland            PL          Polski
4          Rusia             RU          Ruski
```

PHP 7 and mysqli code:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test');
$key = "SELECT ID FROM countries";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $key);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   foreach ($row as $key) {
      echo $row['name'];
      echo '<br>';
    }
 }
```

This will output `11223344`. When changing the SQL code to `$key = "SELECT ID, NAME FROM countries";` the output will be `1111222233334444` (double the first one). Why is the output double and why will the it add double the ID's when I add an extra row?

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_array` returns 2 row types when unspecified, tell it to just return associative.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are getting any output of `11223344 ` or `1111222233334444 ` from that example provided. The code doesnt match what you are saying is happening (?)

Comment: @Randall whoops, it should echo `$row['ID']'. Then It will output the `11223344`. Apparently this is from having a `while` and `foreach`.

Comment: Ahhh, ok, thats making more sense! :)

Comment: @Jeff It is from not defining the return so it does `MYSQLI_BOTH`, use `MYSQLI_ASSOC`. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: That is correct what @chris85 said. `mysqli_fetch_array` will return each row with both indexed values and named values (two). You can see that by `print_r($row)` in each while loop. So thats why your foreach was doubling it. Just remove that foreach (not needed in your example), and access `$row['ID']` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_array()` fetches data with numeric keys like `$row[0]`.

Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` for named keys like `$row['name']`, and remove the `foreach()` that iterates over them.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['name'];
    echo '<br>';
}
```